# How can I hook up a dryer vent to this duct that doesn't fully come out of the wall?

Tags: hvac, dryer, laundry

My dryer duct comes out of the bottom of the wall at around a 40-45 degree angle. However, the top of the duct is behind the drywall:

[image: dryer duct image]

How do I hook up a dryer hose to this? I'm not sure what to buy, or if I need to cut out drywall around the vent to tape around it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cut the drywall to expose the full circumference of the duct.

Once exposed, there are extensions that can be added to the duct to make attaching a hose easier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to trim the drywall so that it doesn't obstruct the vent tube. It may be possible at that point to pull the end of the tube out of the wall a bit. Then you should be able to connect to it using a standard connector.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a poor installation, but if you skip dryer HOSE and use rigid dryer duct, it appears to be correctly oriented for inserting the male end of a duct fitting into it. Could be it's such a poor installation that if you reach into the duct and lift&pull you can raise the duct so it comes straight out of the wall. It may not be properly secured in the wall, and has fallen into that position after being disconnected. Ideally, if that's the case, you'd cut a big hole in the drywall and affix it properly, then patch the drywall (low stakes drywall repair, it's presumably an area hidden by the appliance.) If it's fixed solidly and the drywall is blocking the top of the pipe, you'll need to trim enough drywall to expose the full pipe opening, at least.

Apart from the pain in the rear of getting it into place correctly, duct is superior to hose in all other ways. Lints up less, contains fire better, cleans easier.

If you insist on using hose, just put a duct coupler or elbow into the wall opening, and connect the hose to that.

[image: Rigid duct] *image source https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/5b79e878-d61e-4aef-bcc7-37ef8689a56a/02631201.jpg?size=lg no endorsement implied*

These are usually sold/stocked with the seam open, so you'll see a pile of flat sheets with worked edges, not a made-up duct, unless the store has one as an example. You cut to length from the crimped end, with your waste at the uncrimped end, unless you do enough duct work to justify the cost of crimping pliers so you can put a male end on what would be the waste otherwise.

[image: Rigid elbow] *image source https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/fdbaaedf-6700-4f81-8e38-a2f389121454/02838811.jpg?size=lg no endorsment implied*

These are sold just like that. Every one of the joints can be rotated to adjust it from 90 degrees to straight, or offset, or any angle inbetween.

Comment: Can you send an example of a duct I can purchase for this? How does the male end stay secure with the opening? Also it feels pretty solidly attached to the wall when I try to move it

Comment: The male end stays secure with the opening because there's 100+ pounds of dryer connected to the female end of the duct, and there's only limited wiggle room permitted by the joints. You get everything adjusted and lined up and slide the dryer into place to push the last fitting home.